# naming elements inside list using lapply

Tags: r

I am learning how to accessing list elements using `lapply` and others to in complex lists. I need to set object names on certain levels but I am stuck at very beginning. So lets create list:

```
my_list=vector("list",3)#create empty list of 3 elements 
names(my_list)=c("1st.element","2nd.eleent","3rd.element")#set names(this is easy) 
my_list=lapply(my_list, function(x) x=vector("list",5))#each element is list consisting 5 elements
```

So now I want to set name each element. I know how to do this using `for`:

`for(i in 1:length(my_list)){names(my_list[[i]])=paste(names(my_list[i]),1:length(my_list[[i]]),sep=".")}`

Output of this loop is my desired output. How to achieve it? I tried different approaches with `lapply` the closest to code above is:

`lapply(my_list[[i]],function(i)names(i)=paste(names(my_list[i]),1:length(my_list[[i]]),sep="."))`

Please keep in mind I am still learning `apply` functions.

Comment: Your for-loop was exacly what I needed! I have been searching all over stackoverflow for a way to add a list element prefix to my columns! Works like a charm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `Map` to loop through the `names` of 'my_list' and the `list` itself, then use `setNames` to name the individual nested `list` elements

```
Map(function(x, y) setNames(x, paste0(y, seq_along(x)))
            , my_list,  names(my_list))
```

---

A similar option using `tidyverse` would be

```
library(purrr)
map2(my_list, names(my_list), ~ set_names(.x, paste0(.y, seq_along(.x))))
```

Or instead of `map2`, `imap` get the names of the `list` as `.y` (as @Moody_Mudskipper commented)

```
imap(my_list, ~ set_names(.x, paste0(.y, seq_along(.x))))
```

Comment: you can use `imap` when `.y == names(.x)` in `map2`